# Inverse of prediction is correct in Scikit Learn Logistic Legression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In the following minimal reproducible dataset, I split a dataset into train and test dataset, fit a logistic regression to the training dataset with scikit learn and predict y based on the `x_test`.

However the `y_pred` or y predictions, are correct only if inversed (e.g 0 = 1, and 1 = 0) calculated like so: `1 - y_pred`. 
Why is this the case? I cant figure out if it is something relating to the scaling of x (I have tried with and without the `StandardScaler`), something related to the logistic regression, or the accuacy score calculation.

In my larger dataset, this is also the case even when using different seeds as random state. I have also tried [this Logistic Regression](https://medium.com/@martinpella/logistic-regression-from-scratch-in-python-124c5636b8ac) with the same result.

**EDIT** as pointed out by @Nester it works without standard scaler for this minimal dataset. Larger dataset avaliable [here](https://pastebin.com/SmdVnuWS), `standardScaler` does nothing on this larger dataset, I'll keep the OP smaller dataset as it might help in explaining the problem.

```
# imports
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# small dataset
Y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
X =[[0.38373581],[0.56824121],[0.39078066],[0.41532221],[0.3996311 ]
    ,[0.3455455 ],[0.55867358],[0.51977073],[0.51937625],[0.48718916]
    ,[0.37019272],[0.49478954],[0.37277804],[0.6108499 ],[0.39718093]
    ,[0.33776591],[0.36384773],[0.50663667],[0.3247984 ]]


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42, stratify=Y)
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)

y_pred = 1 - y_pred #          <- why?

accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
1.0
```

Larger dataset accuracy:

```
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
0.7  # if inversed
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X and Y does not have any relationship at all. Hence, the model is performing poorly. There is reason to say that 1-pred is performing better. If you have more than two classes, then situation would be even more worse.

```
%matplotlib inline 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.15,  stratify=Y)
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(clf.named_steps['standardscaler'].transform(x_train),y_train)
plt.scatter(clf.named_steps['standardscaler'].transform(x_test),y_test)
print(clf.score(x_test,y_test))
```

[image]

The relationship is same for your bigger dataset as well.

[image]

Try to identify other features, which can help you in predicting Y.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the model without the StandardScaler()? Your data looks like it doesn't need to be re-scaled.